# Numerically solving an equation

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Related to a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373295/angle-at-the-suspension-point-of-a-chain) from Math stack exchange, is there a way I can solve an equation numerically using excel?

I know there is a solver in Excel, but it requires user interaction whenever something changes. I want to be able to change some parameters and have the whole worksheet update itself, just like with normal formulas.

The equation that needs solving is the following, with all parameters except *a* known:

```
a*cosh(x/a) - a - s = 0
```

Comment: I misread the question. If you can convert the formula to show `a = ...`, we can help you find the correct function to do that. I suggest you do that in Math.SE, and update your question here.

Comment: Excel will always require user interaction, if you're working with iterative calculations and the Goal Seek tool or the Solver. Another option is to, and it depends on how you input your formulas on your worksheet, allow [circular reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Remove-or-allow-a-circular-reference-8540bd0f-6e97-4483-bcf7-1b49cd50d123), which you can set [parameters](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-formula-recalculation-iteration-or-precision-73fc7dac-91cf-4d36-86e8-67124f6bcce4) like precision or number of iterations.

Comment: Another option also is to code your own functions and subs, which requires implementation on VBA. That would require two inputs: the address to the a cell and the address to the equation cell. Since it is an iterative calculation, you can hard code it to calculate the answer only when changing the a cell or the equation cell, or else excel will recalculate it every time a change is made on the worksheet. Check the On Change [Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel)

Comment: Are you essentially asking how to automatically/conditionally change the formula in a cell?  (though I dont know how, but is that what you're asking?)

Comment: Can we assume that the **sign** of both *x* and *s* are both positive ??

Comment: If you are asking a question about solving a formula with variables in it, you don't need to even mention cosh.  Your question should not be specific to any particular formula so you could surely just choose a simple formula to demonstrate your question,  like =a+x.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent You can, if it helps.

Comment: @Vylix For this specific case, an analytical solution doesn't exist. That is the point of the question: it requires numeric, iterative calculation.

Comment: @Thales VBA would solve this, yes. I don't have any experience with it, though, so I was hoping another answer might exist. Besides, I'd have to research on how to actually write numeric solvers.

Comment: @barlop I know I didn't need to mention it, but it provides a specific problem to solve. I thought a simple equation like y=a+x would just invite comments like: just enter `=y-a`.

Comment: @Thales I wasn't aware circular references could work like that. It sounds like a cool method to look into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is **not** a general solution, just a demonstration of technique.

In **A1** enter some small positive value, say *0.001*.  In **B1** enter a REALLY big positive value, say *1.E+15*.  In **S1** enter an *s* value, say *7*.  In **X1** enter an *x* value, say *10*.

In **C1** enter `=(A1+B1)/2` and in **D1** enter your formula:

```
=C1*COSH(X$1/C1)-C1-S$1
```

[image]

Clearly **C1** is the average of a lower and upper bound.  Because it is also REALLY big, the formula yields a value approximately *-s*

In **A2** enter `=IF(D1>0,C1,A1)` and in **B2** enter `=IF(D1<0,C1,B1)` and copy both **C1** and **D1** downwards.

In row 2, we have cut the interval in half.  Then copy **A2** through **D2** downwards:

[image]

In each row, the interval is half the interval in the previous row.  Near the bottom:

[image]

So the numerical solution is approximately 8.097966368

***NOTES:***

- This will converge much faster using Newton-Raphson.
- A VBA user defined function will permit the convergence to terminate automatically.
- For some values of *s* and *x*, the initial value in **A1** may need to be modified.

Comment: Excellent use of both numerical mathematics and excel, it's a +1 for me!

Comment: Will fix later........

Comment: @relatively_random .............DONE!